# JQuery's ajax post request does not work as it's supposed to be

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

The page's link is: localhost/mysite/create-user

This is the code:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" name = "signUp1F" id = "signUp1F">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="pskil" id ="pskil" type="text" placeholder = "Doctor, Trainer, Human Resource etc.">
            <input type="hidden" name="neoid" id="neoid" value="<?php echo $neoid; ?>" />
            <span><button id = "plus" class="btn btn-success">Plus</button></span>
            <div id="skillsAdded"></div>
        </form>
```

The jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#plus').click( function(event){
        var pskil = $('#pskil').val();
        var neoid = $('#neoid').val();
        if( !pskil){
            alert( "Please write a skill.");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "localhost/mysite/add-skill",
            data: { pskil: pskil, neoid: neoid},
            success: function( response){
                $('#skillsAdded').append( pskil + "<br>");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The purpose is this: user enters a skill value to the input, clicks the Plus button, an ajax request is sent to add the skill to the database. And the code that handles this request is on localhost/mysite/add-skill.

But things go wrong. When I click the "plus" button, it goes to the page localhost/mysite/create-user?pskil=php&neoid=53. What can possibly make this direction? I've been working on this issue for almost 2 hours and I cannot manage to handle it.

Comment: The *lonely* button submits the form, that's all

Comment: Nevermind my answer. preventDefault() or return false on the click event. I tested locally without a button, apologies for the misleading answer.

Comment: @Alexander, which lonely button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your button tag submit your form. Here is a updated JavaScript source that you can use. jQuery got a built in preventDefault() method for events. This will for an example prevent the button to submit the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#plus').click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var pskil = $('#pskil').val();
        var neoid = $('#neoid').val();
        if( !pskil){
            alert( "Please write a skill.");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "localhost/mysite/add-skill",
            data: { pskil: pskil, neoid: neoid},
            success: function( response){
                $('#skillsAdded').append( pskil + "<br>");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tryout: http://jsfiddle.net/3A7Mg/1/